# Extract substring within string

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

Given the following string:

```
[0.020s][info][class,load] opened: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\lib\modules
```

How can I write a Windows batch file, `.bat`, or command script, `.cmd`, to extract only the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1` part of the string?         *(Using its position is not satisfactory)*.

Comment: What did you try ? Are you really using MS-DOS ? Where is the string ? Do you just have this line in the file ?

Comment: `C:\Program Files` is not DOS, and there's no JDK for DOS either. DOS and Windows cmd are [not the same](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if the string is in a file called `input.txt`:

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims=\:" %%a in (input.txt) do set "$path=%%a:\%%b"
echo %$path:~1%
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the string is contained in a variable you can use string substitution:

```
set string="[0.020s][info][class,load] opened: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\lib\modules"
set "jdkmod="%string:*: =%"
set jdkmod
```

Sample output:

```
jdkmod="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\lib\modules"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question where the string is coming from, or if it has already been filtered for the specific output you are using for that string.

The following assumes that you were looking for the path up to the parent directory of `lib`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "String=[0.020s][info][class,load] opened: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\lib\modules"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('"Echo %String:\lib\=&:%"') Do Set "var=%%~B"
Echo [%var%]
Pause
```

Sample output:

```bat
[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1]
```